# Whats wrong with this one line bash script?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Major bash-noob here. Writing my second program again. For my homework, I need to write a number of grep statements using regexps.

This is the first one I'm trying to write. 
I'm saving it as grep.bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
egrep bright_side_of_life 'the'
```

The error I  get is :

```
egrep: the: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you flipped the arguments of egrep.

First comes the pattern, second the file.